# Mascara JQuery ao digitar texto

Tags: jquery, html

Estive pesquisando algumas máscaras Jquery para aplicar em um sistema, mas notei que em alguns exemplos a máscara é exibida quando se clica no input, e em outros casos a máscara é aplicada durante a digitação.

Como faço para obter o segundo caso? Atualmente estou usando o código abaixo e obtive a primeira opção.

```
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.estoque").mask("999.99");
});
</script>
<body>
<label for="EST_MIN">
    <input type="text" class="estoque" name="EST_MIN" id="EST_MIN" MAXLENGTH="6"        value="" />
</label>
```

Comment: Com o [jQuery Mask](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) ele faz isso automático.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sempre tenho problemas com essas mascaras, eu simplesmente mudo o jeito da chamada para que elas funcionem. Por exemplo você pode mudar a implementação dela e colocar no evento on focus segue abaixo um exemplo.

```
jQuery(function($){
   $(".estoque").live('focusin',function(){
       $(this).mask('999.99');
   });
});
```

> O método live depende da versão do seu jQuery caso não funcione mude ele para o método on como exemplo abaixo.

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("input").on('focusin','.estoque',function(){
       $(this).mask('999.99');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você esteja querendo que os números comecem a ser digitados da direita pra esquerda, ou seja, formatação enquanto digita.

Você pode usar o jquery.inputmask.js que tem essa possibilidade.  Você pode ver mais sobre esse plugin jquery (e suas extensões) em http://bseth99.github.io/projects/jquery-ui/5-jquery-masks.html

Note o primeiro campo Decimal que ele tem como exemplo.  Deve ser o que você quer.  Analise o código fonte dele para ver como chamar e os arquivos que precisa baixar.